# MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call | Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-msal

Adding Microsoft Authentication and Microsoft Graph to my Blazor Server application as following (Program.cs):

```
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

In my Index.razor.cs I'm calling this GraphClient and try to get information about the currently logged in User:

```
private User? user;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            user = await SecondGraphServiceClient.Me.Request().Select("CompanyName,Mail,Country,DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,GivenName,Surname").GetAsync();
        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Now when I run this locally, it's giving me the mentioned Error:

> MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the
> AcquireTokenSilent call.

After that, **the OnInitializedAsync method automatically runs again and everything is working fine** (the User is logged in) and I get the requested information about the logged in user.

**In Production, the OnInitializedAsync method doesn't run twice** (the try/catch block), which leaves me with the mentioned Error.

How can I overcome this Error or only call the SecondGraphClient when the user is already logged in? Does have something to do with the InMemoryTokenCache or is it another problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you got `No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call` means the graph API couldn't work as expected because no use was detected to sign in, and you also mentioned that `OnInitializedAsync method automatically runs again`.

I test in my side with your code and I didn't reproduce your issue but the `OnInitializedAsync` executed twice indeed. I deduce that your issue is due to [prerender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server) of Razor components on the server. We could check the `_Host.cshtml` to see if it has `<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />`. I mean the first time `OnInitializedAsync` method was triggered in the server which hasn't got the signed in user. So we might switch to use `<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />` instead.

Or to make sure that our app could get the signed in user, we might put the ms graph API calling method into for example `OnAfterRenderAsync`.

```
<div>user display name is : 
    @if (user == null)
    {
        <label>no user</label>
    }
    else
    {
        <label>@user.DisplayName</label>
    }
</div>

private User? user;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    try
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            user = await SecondGraphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var mesg = ex.GetBaseException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I already changed the render-mode to "Server". If I comment out the try/catch block, the OnInitializedAsync method only runs once (expected behavior when render-mode is set to Server).But with the try/catch block it runs twice, but only in local development!

Comment: If I put the statement in the OnAfterRenderAsync method, no change occurs. I still get an error: ErrorCode: user_null

Comment: could you pls share more codes or a minimal sample for reproducing the issue?

Comment: There's not much more to it unfortunately.. I'm just wondering why it is working in Development and not in Production and why the try/catch block is being run twice in Development and not in Production. I think it has nothing to do with permission or the scopes, since it's working locally..

Comment: it's also weird for me, but if we just want to troubleshoot it, we might try to find if there were any difference between the 2 environment...